# Order list making the line numbers hrefs

Tags: html

I'm currently using a ordered list and would like to be able to link to a specific line by using line the numbers as links to them.

```
<ol>
  <li id="line10" href="#line10">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

I was wondering if you guys know of a way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code sample is invalid; an `href` attribute is not allowed in `li`. Please explain the *goal*. Should the content of a list be a link to itself? Or that the list item should be linkable? It is, if it has an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `href` attribute is not a valid attribute of `li`

If you want the `li` to be a clickable link, linking to itself, nest an `a` element inside:

```
<li id="line10"><a href="#line10">Coffee</a></li>
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't really think there way a way to do it. The thing is that there can be hrefs in the line so I don't want to make the whole line one. Thanks for you time!